# MVVM pattern on Jboss Errai

Tags: gwt, mvvm, jboss, errai

With feature like [Data Binding](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Errai+UI#ErraiUI-DataBinding), is it possible to adopt a MVVM pattern on [Jboss Errai](http://www.jboss.org/errai)?

Answer (score 2):

The MVVM pattern is a design-pattern, so it is theoretically possible to use it with any language or UI framework. However, MVVM works best if the framework supports data-binding. Whether you use it or not is your choice.